# How to concatenate values from joined table in specific order, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat

Regarding to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960662/how-to-multiple-concatenate-values-from-multiple-relation-tables-in-a-single-mys?noredirect=1#comment74960699_43960662), I run into problem of sorting joined values.

In this example, I have a table with offers which is not important in this question, but it is main table:

```
Table offers
----------------------------
id  title            price
----------------------------
1   Offer 1 title    300 Eur
2   Offer 2 title    250 Eur
3   Offer 3 title    350 Eur
```

There is a list of department cities:

```
Table departments
----------------------------
id  name
----------------------------
1   London
2   Leeds
3   Manchester
4   Glasgow
```

and relation table with offer table

```
Table rel_departments
------------------------
id  offer_id  rel_id
------------------------
1   1         1
2   1         3
3   1         2
4   2         1
5   3         4
```

When running query to get concatenated department cities name, I got the result. However, this result is not in good order.

```
SELECT `offers`.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(`departments`.`name` SEPARATOR ', ') AS departures
FROM `offers`
INNER JOIN `rel_departments` ON (`rel_departments`.`offer_id` = `offers`.id)
INNER JOIN `departments` ON (`rel_departments`.`rel_id` = `departments`.id)
GROUP by offers.id
```

I got result:

```
id  departures
----------------------------------------
1   London, Manchester, Leeds
2   London
3   Glasgow
```

This is OK, but I need to sort them in (in this way descending order by id in relation table) which means I need result to be (for the first offer id) Leeds, Manchester, London

I have tried everything but with no success. Any idea?

p.s. [HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae7201/1) is a sqlfiddle demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ORDER BY in GROUP_CONCAT function.

**Query**

```
SELECT `offers`.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(`departments`.`name` ORDER BY `offers`.id SEPARATOR ', ') AS departures
FROM `offers`
INNER JOIN `rel_departments` ON (`rel_departments`.`offer_id` = `offers`.id)
INNER JOIN `departments` ON (`rel_departments`.`rel_id` = `departments`.id)
GROUP by offers.id
```

**Result**

```
| id |                departures |
|----|---------------------------|
|  1 | Leeds, Manchester, London |
|  2 |                    London |
|  3 |                   Glasgow |
```

see demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae7201/3

Comment: Yep, but actually I have to sort them by rel_departments.id but logic is the same and it works! thanks!